# Image Planes in Eevee Appearing at Incorrect Depths

Tags: rendering, image, eevee-render-engine

I'm not certain if this is a bug or if this is just how Eevee works, but images I import as planes are acting very strangely. I'm trying to make a  mock-up room using them, but in the Eevee engine they're displaying oddly, the only way I can describe it is not displaying at the depth it's actually at? Using Cycles it displays everything properly, so I'll just use that for the time being, but this really threw me for a loop.

I tried updating to the most recent stable release (2.82 to 2.82a), tried re-opening the file, restarting, none of that fixed it. I appreciate any information, thank you.

(It may not look like it in the images, but in the Eevee screencaps both walls are actually intersecting and clipping with each other, along with the ground plane)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This has a rather simple solution.

You need to set the material blend mode to *Opaque*.
When using *Images as planes* addon, it's set to *Alpha blend* by default.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I came across this as well and was pulling my hair out.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help :).